# Question about half subtractor circuit

Tags: digital-logic

I know that the borrow output in a half subtractor is represented as   (-A)B. Wouldn’t it also be correct to represent it as the difference output and B. If that sounded confusing here’s a picture of what I mean[image]

Comment: what does the Karnaugh map tell you?

Comment: Try to eye-ball delay time on gate level & CMOS switch level, "in-chip" as well as going through input protection & output driver.

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean. I just started learning digital electronics so I don’t know all the  jargon that is used

Answer (score 0):

Sure, in principle the answer is "**yes**", since your second circuit has the same truth table.

But for many usages it is important to have a low propagation delay. An XOR is commonly built from multiple simpler gates and has some delay, and then you add the delay of the AND, which gives a comparatively long delay for B<sub>0</sub>.

The first circuit commonly has shorter delay times, only adding the ones of NOT and AND.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I was thinking that there was some optimization that I wasn’t aware of with the default way.

Comment: @YinkaEromomene Depending on the optimization function (academical or for existing gates) I'm sure you will find that the second circuit becomes the first circuit. This is left as an exercise to the reader. ;-)